How can a plaintiff find an attorney to represent him in a civil complaint
A pastor of a church was evicted because the County sold his church for purported Tax Delinquency. While no taxes were due. Several County Officials violated plaintiff’s constitutional rights.

The same way they find a plumber or a doctor
Word of mouth, advertising, online research, etc.

Yellow & White Pages still exist and contain lists.
